# Finding vector perpendicular to R3 plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What I know about the surface is that it has point (1,1,2) and 2 vectors [1,2,3] and [3,4,5]
How do I solve this? :<

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Well, I tried to solve this for half an hour with no luck. I know that I have to find [A,B,C] from A(x-1)+B(y-1)+C(z-2)+D=0 but I don't know much else.

Comment: I think by "surface" and "$R^3$-plane" you mean a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, right?

Comment: yes, english is not my native language, sorry.

Comment: Have you leaned yet about the crossproduct of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Yes, the crossproduct of two vectors is perpendicular to both of them, would that be what i am looking for? if so, why is there a point in task aswell?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Given two vectors $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb R^3$, the crossproduct $v\times w$ will give a normal to all planes that are parallel to each of $v$ and $w$ (provided $v$ and $w$ are not parallel).  This will help you to determine the equation of this parallel class of planes, and the given point will determine the plane you want uniquely.

The simplest equation for a plane is the so-called scalar form:

$$A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0) + C(z-z_0)=0$$

where $\langle A,B,C\rangle$ is any normal to the plane, and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is any point on the plane.

Comment: okay, so I have the crossproduct [-2,4,-2]. plane would be then -2(x-1)+4(y-1)-2(z-2)=0 .. and what now? :f

Comment: Well, unless I misinterpreted the question, you're finished.

Comment: but then.. why would there be a point (1,1,2) in my task? I mean, I could just crossproduct those 2 vectors without it and I would get what I want, right?

Comment: Please restate the problem completely as it appears in your book (or in your notes).

Comment: Well, it's in polish - plane  r∈R^3 is defined by 2 vectors [], [] and a point (). Find vector that is perpendicular to this plane.

Comment: In that case, you're absolutely right!  We don't need the point at all.  Nice obsrvation on your part.  (Warning: you're absolutely sure they're giving you two vectors and a point, right?  It's not three points they're giving you, right?)

Comment: Yes, I am sure, and mainly that's why I spent so much on it.. well thanks for your answer, I learned a ton anyway :D

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just some hint, I might expand my answer later. From having the point $A(1,1,2)$ and vectors $ \mathbf{u} = [u_1,u_2,u_3]=[1,2,3]$ and $\mathbf{v} = [v_1,v_2,v_3] = [3,4,5] $ you obtain parametric expression of the plane $\tau \in \mathbb{R}^3$. That means $\tau = A + t\mathbf{u} + s\mathbf{v}$, where $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$ are scalars. In coordinates:
\begin{align*}
x &= 1 + t\cdot 1 + s \cdot 3\\
y &= 1 + t\cdot 2 + s \cdot 5\\
z &= 2 + t\cdot 3 + s \cdot 6\\
\end{align*}

So, by specifying $t, s$ you can get every point from the plane. But for plane we have another expression called *implicit* expression, which looks something like this $ax+by+cz+d = 0$. The point I am trying to make is, that if we took $(a,b,c) = \mathbf{n}$ we get a *normal* vector of the plane $\tau$, which is, as you might have guessed already, perpendicular to $\tau$.

And more, every other vector perpendicular to the plane $\tau$ we get by multiplying $\mathbf{n}$ by any scalar.

Transforming back and forth between parametric and implicit expression is another question, but I think there is plenty of material covering that topic, and it is one o'clock in the morning in my country, so I better be going.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the parametric equations of the plane: 
$$x = 1 + 1\lambda + 3\mu $$
$$y = 1 + 2\lambda + 4\mu$$
$$z = 2 + 3\lambda + 5\mu$$
and then solve for $\mu$ and $\lambda$...

Comment: How do I know those 2 vectors are parallel to the plane I am looking for? What after I have μ and λ?

Comment: Those two vectors are the ones that you have been given...they define your plane.

Comment: You use the first two equations to compute $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, put the results in the third equation and you are done...

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for help. I've been ill for a month and couldn't attend lectures and have some big gaps in knowledge and every task is a struggle. Thanks :)